# node.js degrading performance after using child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js

After running a child process ( using exec or spawn ) I have found that the performance of my node.js application decreases by a factor of 10. Below is a contrived example and output.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function runExpensiveOperation(times) {
  while(times > 0) {
    console.time('expensiveOperation');
    var str = 'lorem';
    for ( var i=0;i< 10000000; i++) {
      // string concatenation
      str = str.length < 1000 ? str + str : '';
      // math operation
      i * i * i;
    }
    console.timeEnd('expensiveOperation');
    times--;
  }
}

console.log('PRE EXEC');
runExpensiveOperation(10);
exec('echo "hello"');
console.log('POST EXEC');
runExpensiveOperation(10);
```

Output:

```
PRE EXEC
expensiveOperation: 66.458ms
expensiveOperation: 65.735ms
expensiveOperation: 69.237ms
expensiveOperation: 65.269ms
expensiveOperation: 69.133ms
expensiveOperation: 65.639ms
expensiveOperation: 67.944ms
expensiveOperation: 63.595ms
expensiveOperation: 64.153ms
expensiveOperation: 65.093ms
POST EXEC
expensiveOperation: 715.861ms
expensiveOperation: 739.671ms
expensiveOperation: 714.546ms
expensiveOperation: 714.845ms
expensiveOperation: 745.719ms
expensiveOperation: 743.240ms
expensiveOperation: 716.481ms
expensiveOperation: 732.916ms
expensiveOperation: 736.576ms
expensiveOperation: 742.416ms
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? Has anyone come across something similar before, or could this possible be an issue with my personal machine? I am currently running node version 5.8.0.

In addition, this problem only occurs if the string concatenation AND math operation are run in the expensiveOperation - if either are commented out then there is no issue.

**UPDATE**

This actually happens only AFTER the chid process has finished - there is no effect when the child process is running, please see the following updated code example and output :

```
console.log('PRE SPAWN');
runExpensiveOperation(10);
// simple endpoint that holds the http request for 3 seconds
var process = spawn('curl',['https://httpbin.org/delay/3']);
process.on('exit', function(){
  console.log('SPAWN EXIT');
  runExpensiveOperation(10);
});
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('POST SPAWN');
  runExpensiveOperation(10);
},100);
```

Output:

```
PRE SPAWN
expensiveOperation: 68.140ms
expensiveOperation: 64.574ms
expensiveOperation: 65.773ms
expensiveOperation: 71.974ms
expensiveOperation: 63.766ms
expensiveOperation: 66.595ms
expensiveOperation: 71.057ms
expensiveOperation: 62.015ms
expensiveOperation: 76.570ms
expensiveOperation: 75.234ms
POST SPAWN
expensiveOperation: 75.726ms
expensiveOperation: 70.672ms
expensiveOperation: 66.938ms
expensiveOperation: 68.169ms
expensiveOperation: 73.752ms
expensiveOperation: 76.147ms
expensiveOperation: 68.912ms
expensiveOperation: 75.144ms
expensiveOperation: 74.116ms
expensiveOperation: 67.488ms
SPAWN EXIT
expensiveOperation: 782.959ms
expensiveOperation: 769.501ms
expensiveOperation: 771.076ms
expensiveOperation: 737.611ms
expensiveOperation: 708.857ms
expensiveOperation: 716.193ms
expensiveOperation: 704.008ms
expensiveOperation: 707.031ms
expensiveOperation: 701.662ms
expensiveOperation: 714.501ms
```

**BACKGROUND**

I originally found this issue because I was using spawn to call ffmpeg to decode an mp3. As the audio samples were being returned I was calculating the FFT. I noticed that the first time I did this ( while ffmpeg was still outputting audio samples ) the computation time was fine, but the second time ( after the first spawn had finished ) it was very slow.

Comment: Can't replicate, running 5.8.0 on a very basic Ubuntu machine. [Some output.](http://pastebin.com/raw/6UF1RRjm)

Comment: Hmm, here's my results http://pastebin.com/N0xxhHL8 - might be something

Comment: Interesting! I _can_ replicate similar results on OS X 10.11.3, Node 5.8.0: [Some more output.](http://pastebin.com/raw/2D9srzh6) Commenting out either of the string or math operations does decrease the runtime significantly.

Comment: Can this just be because you're firing up another process that is competing for the system CPUs while node.js runs?  What if you run the second `runExpensiveOperation(10)` in a `setTimeout()` of 10 seconds or so that lets the `exec()` operation complete?  And, how many CPUs do you have in the system you are trying this on?

Comment: Ubuntu machine with no issues has a single core, OS X machine exhibiting issues has four. `setTimeout` has no effect.

Comment: For completeness: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5636

Comment: I am using a Macbook Air with 2 cores running OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: In an interesting twist, the slowdown only happens AFTER the child process has finished - there is no slowdown while the the child process is executing. Please see my update.